# How do I get out of while Loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have created `LinkedList` and i am trying to make the user modify for one of them. So far the while loop searches for one by course id then if found the user will asked to edit. But the problem it asks the user twice to edit.

I have tried using  "break" under the `if` statement and even `exit(0)` but it doesn't work. It keeps me in the while loop twice when it supposed to get me out once after the `if` statement has been executed.

```
template <typename T> node<T>* ModifyByCourseId(node<T> *front, string className, string courseId)
{
    node<T> *curr = front;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        if (curr->classId == courseId) {
            cout << curr->classId << " " << curr->classDescrip << "." << curr->credit << ":" << curr->creditHr 
                 << curr->Prerequiste << ":" << curr->PreReq << endl; // print the current node's value to the screen
            cout << "Please Modify course title." << endl;          
            getline(cin, curr->classDescrip);
            cout << "Please enter Credit hour(s)." << endl;
            cin >> curr->creditHr;
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Please enter class pre-requisite(s) if there are more than one separate them by a space." << endl;
            getline(cin, curr->PreReq);
            break;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: @WasiAhmad Why? Using == is exactly the same.

Comment: I don't believe that `break` doesn't work. Check if you hit the `if`-block at all.

Comment: @WasiAhmad Encouraged by who? Do you have a source for that claim?

Comment: try proving the code in which you call this function @Sekacorn

Comment: this is not Java, why on earth C++ string encourage `equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: @WasiAhmad. == compares if the string matches what is in the link list

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I called the function twice in the if the statement